# Kerberos ticket for non-elevated user in Windows 10

Tags: kerberos, windows-authentication

I have a non-AD KDC that is used by several database servers in the cloud for authentication. I have also configured my windows machines to authenticate against that same KDC. The goal is to run applications that access those database servers from the windows machine using single sign on.

That windows authentication against the KDC works. However when I login on the  windows machine, the kerberos ticket is cached for an elevated session but not for a non-elevated one.

The applications and python scripts that access those database servers, do indeed work correctly with the cached kerberos tickets, provided they are run in elevated mode.

I would like to be able to use the kerberos ticket to run those apps non-elevated. Is it possible to configure the external KDC authentication mechanism in windows so that the ticket is cached for the non-elevated user?

Details:

So from a non-elevated command prompt:

```
E:\>klist sessions

Current LogonId is 0:0x303fd58
[0] Error calling API LsaGetLogonSessionData on LogonId (0:4ee3f0c): 0x5
[1] Session 3 0:0x31f6bfa MONET\Marcel Negotiate:NewCredentials
[2] Session 3 0:0x303fd58 MONET\Marcel Negotiate:Interactive
[3] Session 3 0:0x303fcf7 MONET\Marcel Kerberos:Interactive
```

But from an elevated prompt:

```
E:\>klist sessions

Current LogonId is 0:0x303fcf7
[0] Session 0 0:0x4ee3f0c NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Negotiate:NewCredentials
[1] Session 3 0:0x31f6bfa MONET\Marcel Negotiate:NewCredentials
[2] Session 3 0:0x303fd58 MONET\Marcel Negotiate:Interactive
[3] Session 3 0:0x303fcf7 MONET\Marcel Kerberos:Interactive
```

You will notice that for the elevated promp, the loginId is the Kerberos:Interactive session and indeed, from the non-elevated command prompt "klist" shows no tickets, while from the elevated command prompt "klist" shows all the kerberos tickets.

Comment: I never did get a solution for this. However the workaround has been to use windows users that don't have administrative priveleges and thus the Kerberos ticket gets cached with the correct session.

When adding a user "xyz" to windows that I wish to have admin privileges, I create a pair of accounts: "xyz" which is non-priveleged and for regular use,  and "xyzAdmin" with admin privileges. The admin accounts are used when the user wishes to elevate.

At first this started as a workaround but I have grown to like the slight friction this introduces to elevation, making you think first.